# Если на макете( PSD) большая высота строки, задавать высоту строки как указано в макете или отодвигать отступами?

Tags: html, css

На макете у текста указан line-height:133px. Можно указывать такой lh или же отодвигать отступами?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем принципиальная разница данных подходов? Особенно, если неизвестно как вы верстаете этот макет

Comment: Разница есть. Там может появиться еще одна строка. И как это будет выглядеть с большим lh? Хотя бы в этом есть принципиальная разница.

Comment: Отлично, но об этом известно только вам. Могли бы уточнить вопрос тогда, описав вашу ситуацию более точно

Comment: Тут ответ такой же как и мой комментарий к другому вашему вопросу. Но тут скажу чуть больше: если заказчик никогда не будет редактировать этот элемент и при адаптивности такое позволительно, то можно сделать хоть через `position: absolute`, в противном случае вы должны учитывать наполнение: если его мало как в примере, то располагать текст выше, а кнопки и форму к нижнему краю прижимать, если это будет наполниться, то соблюдать какие-то логичные отступы. Если же это тестовое задание — то пробуйте сами, вам же нужно набираться опыта.